# Разделить секцию на две равные части Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Ситуация следующая: необходимо разделить секцию на 2 (две) равные части. Слева белая, справа серая.
Сверху этих двух секций лежит текст(левая часть) и форма(правая часть).
Этот контент не должен уходить за рамки `.container`, в то время как фон слева и фон справа должны растягиваться на весь `.wrapper` (1920px) .

Также, помимо белого фона на левой части лежит картинка. Я вроде бы понял, что она должны располагаться абсолютно этого блока, но вот как растянуть блок на всю ширину, но при этом контент двух блоков сохранить в рамках `.container` .

Пробовал несколько вариантов.. с `.container-fluid` - тогда всё растягивается на всю ширину и контент не исключение. Пробовал располагать без `.container` вовсе, тогда нет границ.

Должно же быть какое-то решение...
заранее благодарен!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-block col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <p><strong>Колбаса “Львовская”</strong> на ваш стол</p>
      <p>Вся продукция TM «ERICREN» изготовлена по традиционным рецептам ,что позволило добиться превосходных вкусовых качеств мясных изделий.</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-block col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <form>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        </div>


        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
          <select class="form-control" id="kind">
           <option>Выбрать изделие</option>
           <option>Изделие 1</option>
           <option>Изделие 2</option>
           <option>Изделие 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: вот итог...]

Сейчас это выглядит вот так..
собственно текст необходимо сместить слева и справа, чтобы он не вылазил за рамки контейнера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте ваш код и скриншотом покажите что необходимо

Comment: отредактировал. 
css не добавлял, смысла нет.
меня интересует разметка только. а все остальное надеюсь додумаю..

Comment: такой вариант подойдет? - https://jsfiddle.net/oaLhykgr/

Comment: @soledar10 да! Фон да , подскажите изображение как растягивать на всю половину враппера , то есть за рамки контейнера?

Comment: С абсолютным позиционированием не получается , так как текст тоже располагается абсолютно

Comment: так? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/oaLhykgr/3/

Comment: @soledar10 в таком случае нет привязки к блоку левому и на моб устройстве она будет просто ниже контейнера ..

Answer (score 1):

Может кому-то в будущем пригодится

```css
.section-form-bg {
 position: relative;
}
.section-form-bg > .container {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
.section-form-bg > .container .text-block {
 color: #fff;
}
.section-form-bg:before,
.section-form-bg:after {
 content: " ";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 0;
}
.section-form-bg:before {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url('https://ichigarev.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/kids2.jpg');
 left: 0px;
 right: 50%;
}
.section-form-bg:after {
 right: 0px;
 left: 50%;
}
.section-form-bg:after,
.form-block {
 background-color: #ccc;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .section-form-bg:before,
 .section-form-bg:after {
  display: none;
 }
 .text-block {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://ichigarev.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/kids2.jpg');
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid section">
 <div class="row section-form">
  <div class="section-form-bg">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="text-block col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <h2><strong>Колбаса “Львовская”</strong> на ваш стол</h2>
      <p>Вся продукция TM «ERICREN» изготовлена по традиционным рецептам ,что позволило добиться превосходных вкусовых качеств мясных изделий.</p>
     </div>
     <div class=" form-block col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="form-block-title text-center">Заказать сейчас</h2>
      <form>
       <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
       </div>
       <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
       </div>
       <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
       </div>
       <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <select class="form-control" id="kind">
         <option>Выбрать изделие</option>
         <option>Изделие 1</option>
         <option>Изделие 2</option>
         <option>Изделие 3</option>
        </select>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```